# Possibility to add a configuration xml to MyBatis at runtime

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm now trying to extend features of an existed production which loads and parses a MyBatis configuration xml file in booting. The new features also have their mapper xml files and a configuration xml file while just add these mapper files together:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false" />
    </settings>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="mapper/a.xml" />
        <mapper resource="mapper/b.xml" />
        <mapper resource="mapper/c.xml" />
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

And then, I use `XMLConfigBuilder` class to configurate the new configuration file just as what the existed production does.

```java
XMLConfigBuilder parser = new XMLConfigBuilder(<configuration file>, "", properties);
Configuration configuration = parser.getConfiguration();
configuration.setEnvironment(environment);
parser.parse();
```

However, it seem the code does not work at all. So, may I know whether it is possible to add a configuration xml to MyBatis at runtime and how can it do?

Comment: Do you mean that there are two configuration XML files? Then the answer is 'no'. You can add mappers or change options of a `Configuration` instance, but you have to do it in your Java code.

Comment: Yes, there are indeed two configuration files, one in the existed production and another in the extended production. And would you tell me how I can add the three mapper files programmatically please?

Comment: You can get the instance of `Configuration` via `SqlSessionFactory` e.g. `sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration()`. Then, to add mappers, you can use `Configuration#addMapper()`. If you are using Spring Boot, check out [ConfigurationCustomizer](http://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/#using-a-configurationcustomizer).

Comment: The `Configuration#addMapper()` method requires a mapper class. However, in my case, there are no new mapper classes. Let me explain it more detail. The existed production provides the mapper classes and its mapper xml file, and what the extended production does is just provide some new queries in a new mapper xml file. Thus, these new mapper xml files need to be added.

Comment: Well, there may be no good workaround for such scenario. I would suggest to copy and modify the configuration XML from the existing production and use it in the extended production (i.e. don't use the old XML configuration at all). It would be technically possible to read the old XML config and modify it before building `SqlSessionFactory` which takes `Reader` or `InputStream`, but I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind reply. That is to say, it is impossible to add neither a configuration xml file (if there has already one) nor an attached mapper xml file (if not use some xml file modification method) to MyBatis in runtime. Am I right?

Comment: That may be correct if you cannot add Java interfaces corresponding to your XML mapper files.